# Broken push to close latch, drawer closed

Tags: cabinets, drawers

How can I open a push to open latch drawer stuck closed by a faulty latch? 
Can anybody please provide me with some tips/tricks and advice as to how I may go about opening the drawer? It is full, I have no access to the mechanism from back, below or either side, drawer fully encased by cabinetry. The rails are on the side of the drawer, not able to push it anywhere to open. I have not been able to find any solutions online. Very frustrating!! 
Thank you all.[image][image][image][image]

Answer (score 1):

Most of this style I have installed are magnetic. If you can’t get a finger behind it a screwdriver may be needed to pop it open.